# What does "isn't in half as much ... as" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Her 15-year-old son Jamie (breakout star Lucas Jade Zumann) isn't in half as much adolescent turmoil as his mom imagines, and is mainly concerned about things like her veiled loneliness and heavy cigarette habit. ("When I started, they weren't bad for you," she says. "They were just stylish.")

Comment: Could you link to the source for this, if available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means his mum imagines that he's in more than twice as much turmoil than the amount he's actually in.  He's in **less than half as much** as his mum fears.  He would have to be in **more** than twice as much turmoil to equal his mum's fears about him.